# Articulating is to speaking as ___ is to writing

Tags: single-word-requests

> Blind John has difficulty articulating the words verbally to tell Sally how much he loves her
>
> Mute John has difficulty _______ the words in writing to tell Sally how much he loves her

Also do you say the words or his words as he can't think of them.

Another example to simplify the context.

> Tom is 12 years old. His teacher tells his parents he is very good at articulating verbally ideas but has difficulty ..... the words to paper.

Comment: Personally, I would have said *composing the necessary words to tell Sally...*

Comment: Both your examples sound unnatural to me. If blind John has difficulty articulating the words verbally, that means he has trouble _pronouncing_ the words, which I don't think is what you are going for. I would use ***find*** in both cases: he has difficulty finding the right words to tell Sally/write to Sally how much he loves her.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The verb *articulate* has more than one meaning, only one of which is synonymous with *pronounce*. And I am sure that blind John's difficulty was not with his pronunciation, but with articulating - meaning *having or showing the ability to speak fluently and coherently*. (Oxford Dictionaries)

Comment: @WS2 Perhaps it's just me, but I cannot force _articulate_ into that sense when used transitively with _the words_ as the object. If the sentence had been “Blind John has difficulties articulating how much he loves Sally”, then that is the obvious meaning—but it's a very stretchy stretch to me to apply that meaning to “articulating the words”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The OED provides several examples, including, *1952   R. Ellison Invisible Man xiii. 221   We need a good speaker... Someone who can articulate the grievances of the people.*. But interestingly it quotes another sense of *articulate*, meaning "to express or convey, especially through non-verbal means". *2006 Independent (Nexis) 24 Nov. 24   This period of European cultural history, when paintings were articulating the first expressions of sexual liberation.* But I still think that *compose* would be a better word for mute John to write.

Comment: @WS2 Those both sound natural enough—note that in both cases, the object is an abstract notion that one can articulate into words; you could actually add “into words” into the first (and with a bit of poetic licence even the second) example and it would still work fine, or replace “articulate” with “put into words”. But “he had difficulties articulating/putting into words the words to say…” doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47342/discussion-between-ws2-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Comment: 'Articulate' works fine for writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Less formal would be *putting the words on paper*. More formal would be *composing* a text.

[**Put on paper**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+on+paper)<sup>1</sup> means:

> Fig. to write something down. 
>   *‘You have a great idea for a novel. Now put it on paper. I'm sorry, I can't discuss your offer until I see something in writing. Put it on paper, and then we'll talk.’*

[**Compose**](https://books.google.com/books?id=anecAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=oxford%20dictionary&pg=PA357#v=onepage&q&f=false)<sup>2</sup> means:

> Phrase (a letter or piece of writing) with great care and thought.
>   *‘the first sentence is so hard to compose’*

---

**References**:

<sup>1</sup> The McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs © 2002
<sup>2</sup> The Oxford Dictionary of English by Angus Stevenson © 2010

Comment: lots of good answers given but I guess *composing* seem to fit the example I gave the best

Answer (score 4):

It's still *articulating*, no matter how it's achieved.

Why can't a mute think of words? Helen Keller was blind, deaf and dumb but she eventually learned to speak (and gave public lectures).

[American Sign Language: articulation](http://www.lifeprint.com/asl101/pages-signs/a/articulation.htm)

[Wikipedia: Helen Keller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Keller)

Comment: I'm not trying to convey the words for  thinking. That is why I compared it with articulated (verbally) to get the writing equivalent.

Comment: I see. I sort of assumed that you were talking about sign language (although you did day "write"). How about *expressing*?

Comment: Both very goods answers. Expressing and articulating. Thanks.

Comment: *articulate* : "able to express ideas clearly and effectively in speech or writing"  "clearly expressed and easily understood" –MW

Comment: Some people have learning disabilities which differentially affect their ability to articulate their thoughts in speech vs. in writing, so you might want two words to distinguish between these cases. You could use "articulate" for the verbal side since it is connotated with oral speech, especially if used in contrast with a word like "compose." But it might be better to find a different word that doesn't apply to both speaking and writing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [committing the words to paper](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/commit-something-to-paper-writing) which means to write down: but also carries the connotation of making the statement definite, or of committing oneself to a position or course of action.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to emphasize the mechanical difficulty of the action, [penning](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/penning).

If you want to emphasize the intellectual act of putting the thought into words you could use [composing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compose).